# Update UIView frame size inside a UITableView - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, ios8

I have a UIView inside a UITableView like this

[image]

The problem is when I try to resize height of my UIView programmatically ,the existing cells inside of UITableView didn't move up
i have been tried update 
`UITableview size` ,

```
UITableviewwrapperview
```

and I have been try update

```
TableView.contentInset

TableView.contentOffset
```

size,remove Auto Layout and Auto Layout , but all same result.

this is my code :

```
@IBAction func SwitchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {

        if sender.on {
            self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height =  self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height + 275


            var  Frame = self.TableView.tableHeaderView!.frame
            Frame.size.height = self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height;
            TableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = Frame



        } else {
           self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height =  self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height - 275


            var  Frame = self.TableView.tableHeaderView!.frame
            Frame.size.height = self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height;
            TableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = Frame

        }

    }
```

and this is result image

1 :
[image]

2 : after update

[image]

Someone please help me and explain which part I missed .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to re-assign view in table header each time when you change your header view frame.

```
YourView.frame =  Frame
TableView.tableHeaderView = YourView
```

And Remove :

```
TableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = Frame
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this if you want to change this in a good way.

```
@IBAction func SwitchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        if sender.on {
            self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height =  self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height + 275
        } else {
           self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height =  self.ViewBOX.frame.size.height - 275
        }
        TableView.tableHeaderView = self.ViewBOX
    }, completion: {
    })
}
```